# Adobe Reader DC filled in data disappears

Tags: pdf, data-recovery, adobe-reader, adobe-reader-dc

A week ago we started using Adobe Reader DC for filling out PDF documents. The new "Fill & sign" tool seemed like a really good option for that.

The documents get edited by 2-3 Users on a network drive using Win7 PCs. No document gets edited by more than one user simultaneously.

It seemed to work just fine, but we started finding some documents to be empty after editing and saving them (though their size grew and the last edited timestamp changed). Those documents have been edited, saved and opened multiple times before without problems.

After some testing it seems that the reader saves multiple versions of the file inside itself (seeing as the filesize grows or stays the same if I replace a big chunk of text with just a few lines).

Has anyone experienced the same problems or has any idea what could be the cause/how to retrieve the filled-out data (apart from VSS, which until now has fortunately saved us from having to fill the documents out from scratch)?